# Embed YouTube videos with fallback solution for corporate proxies

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am wondering whether any of you have ever come accross a solution/function that allows embedding YouTube videos with a fallback solution where an alternative video source is selected if YouTube videos - and the videos only! - are blocked.

One of our corporate clients have access to the web via a proxy server that weeds out flash content served form YouTube. More specifically anything served from ytimg.com is blocked. Since their website is quite heavy on product videos they find it annoying to boot that  clients can watch videos on their site while their own staff can't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to make an Ajax request to something hosted in youTube, i would say something like this:

```
function check_youtube() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL_ON_YOUTUBE,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, textStatus ){
       alert('Woot, Cat videos on the way!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert('Ooops, You suck, proxy blocking your way');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: While the totally unexpected happened - our client's IT department dropped the YouTube block - I think your solution (combined with @ghoti's  suggestions below) would have been worth a shot. Thx!

Comment: Same-Origin Policy will prevent this, no?

Answer (score 2):

It should be clarified that Youtube's Flash *player* is a different thing than the FLV or MP4 file that it plays.  While the Flash player may be served from *.ytimg.com, the streams themselves come from hosts like "o-o.preferred.lga15s18.v2.lscache6.c.youtube.com".

If your client is blocking the former, then you can't use Youtube to get at the videos.  My approach would be to launch your videos from a page that has some sort of automation to recognize your client's IP address range and load up your own copy of [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) or [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) or somesuch.

While you could do this browser-side using something like an ajax call, you still run the risk of overly-conservative corporate IT disabling javascript. (I've seen it happen. It's not pretty.)  Putting the "smarts" on your server leaves you in control, though of course it means you need to know ahead of time what the restrictions are, so that you can adjust for them.

Answer (score 0):

When building the page, you could test for a working connection to ytimg.com, and update the source of the iframe you're using for display accordingly...

```
<iframe src="<?php

//Use a dummy (but valid) ytimg.com url to check for ytimg availability...
$h = get_headers('http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflZzp2iQ.swf');

//If ytimg.com isn't available...
if (stristr($h[0], '200') == FALSE)
{ ?>

    <!--Alt URL-->

<?php

//Otherwise, if ytimg.com is available...
} else { ?>

    <!--YouTube URL-->

<?php } ?> "></iframe>
```

Alternatively, you could politely suggest that your client not be such a hard-ass and allow their employees the occasional YouTube break at work.

**EDIT** Just kidding, I'm an idiot. Use camilo_u's suggestion above.

Comment: This is wrong.  The test needs to be done *BY THE CLIENT*.  A get_headers() call in PHP runs on the server, not the client.  If you're going to do a test for connectivity to ytimg.com, it has to be more like the suggestion by @camilo_u using JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, duh... I probably shouldn't have assumed that the entire server would be behind the proxy. Stupid mistake, I deserve a downvote for this misinformation.